# Strange behavior with Golang append() being affected by fmt.Println()

Tags: go

I noticed some strange behavior with Golang's append().  I understand the basic concept of how slice capacity affects whether a new underlying array gets allocated, but why is whether or not I use a `fmt.Println()` AFTER the append has happened affecting the result of the append?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []byte("AAA")

    b := append(a, []byte("BBB")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b))

    c := append(a, []byte("CCC")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b), " c: ", string(c))

    fmt.Println(&b) //try commenting this out and in and running the program
}
```

Link to run code here: https://play.golang.org/p/jJ-5ZxTBIn

Comment: OP, I simplified your exemple by removing the useless first allocation. You can revert if you disagree.

Comment: This really looks like the compiler wrongly thought it could optimize something out, and only keeps the correct value of b when it's printed after. I verified that this doesn't happen for example with 1.4.2. This should be brought to golang-nuts attention, in case there's not a bug already filled.

Comment: I understand, that this example can confuse you a lot. A nice article is https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals. Slice is something, that points into array - it has remember array, where it point, his lenght and capacity. Usually we don't care about capacity, but in append is very important. Append may share the memory with previous one, if there is enough space, but won't share if it is not. In our case put *fmt.Println(cap(a))* after a=[]byte. It returned me 8. That means, while b and c will be shorter, they will point to the same memory.

Comment: @lofcek I understand that, but I don't think that's what's causing issue here.  The cap() is different depending on whether a print statement is used at the end.

Comment: This is good point. The slice was created by a := []byte("AAA") - but there are no quarantines, what will be capacity of a at the begging. It could depends on version of go (like mentioned Amd), but also on something else like in example. But because you don't have quaranties, good code should not make any assumptions on capacity. But in our  case capacity of a decides, whether b and c will or won't point to the same address and it decides how will be the result.

Comment: @lofcek that's correct.  If you look at the play.golang.org example in the description though, I initialize the slice with capacity of 1000, and we still have the bug regardless.

Comment: That is not fully true - you initialize a to capacity 1000 elements, but in next line, you forgot this value and replace it with a new one.

Comment: Change line  a = []byte("AAA") to a = append(a, []byte("AAA")...)

Comment: Ahh you're right - my mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: 
That is because [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jJ-5ZxTBIn) version is old (`go1.6.2`), use new version.

---

The correct output (using `go version go1.7rc6`) is:

```
 a:  AAA  b:  AAABBB
 a:  AAA  b:  AAACCC  c:  AAACCC
```

---

1- The Go Playground (`go1.6.2`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]byte, 100, 1000)
    a = []byte("AAA")

    b := append(a, []byte("BBB")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b))

    c := append(a, []byte("CCC")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b), " c: ", string(c))

    //fmt.Println(&b) //try commenting this out and in and running the program
}
```

output:

```
 a:  AAA  b:  AAABBB
 a:  AAA  b:  AAABBB  c:  AAACCC
```

---

2- The Go Playground (`go1.6.2`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]byte, 100, 1000)
    a = []byte("AAA")

    b := append(a, []byte("BBB")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b))

    c := append(a, []byte("CCC")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b), " c: ", string(c))

    fmt.Println(&b) //try commenting this out and in and running the program
}
```

output:

```
 a:  AAA  b:  AAABBB
 a:  AAA  b:  AAACCC  c:  AAACCC
&[65 65 65 67 67 67]
```

---

using `go version go1.7rc6`:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]byte, 100, 1000)
    a = []byte("AAA")

    b := append(a, []byte("BBB")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b))

    c := append(a, []byte("CCC")...)
    fmt.Println(" a: ", string(a), " b: ", string(b), " c: ", string(c))

    //fmt.Println(&b) //try commenting this out and in and running the program
}
```

output :

```
 a:  AAA  b:  AAABBB
 a:  AAA  b:  AAACCC  c:  AAACCC
```

Comment: Good to know this has been fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I will summarize:

```
a := make([]byte, 100, 1000)
a = []byte("AAA")
```

creates a slice, in first line, but in second it creates a new array and slice again.

Capacity of this new array depends on version of compiler, therefore good written code should not make any other assumption, than it will be 3 or more.

Be cautious when using append. Returned slice could be shallow or deep copy of previous slice. Which one depends on array capacity. If you need a deep copy, you have to do it manually.

```
b:=make([]byte, len(a))
copy(b,a)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The problem was a compiler bug.